# How to know if a non-homogeneous quadratic function with two variables can be factorized and how to factorize it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, factoring

I'm talking about functions like:
$$p^2-3pq+2q^2-p+3q-2$$
It is fairly easy to factorize homogeneous ones but I don't understand how to deal with non-homogeneous ones. Help?

Comment: Are you interested in how to do it for this kind of polynomials or also for any analytic functions as well? I know a magical method with partial derivatives, which kind of works, but has no practical use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up the factorization as $$(p+Aq+B)(p+Cq+D)$$ and arrive fairly easily, by comparing coefficients, with equations like $$AC=2$$$$A+C=-3$$ so symmetrically $A=-1,C=-2$ and similarly obtain the values of $B$ and $D$

Answer (score 2):

$p^2-(3q+1)p+2q^2+3q-2$ is a quadratic in $\,p\,$ with discriminant:

$$
\Delta = (3q+1)^2-4(2q^2+3q-2)=q^2 - 6 q + 9=(q-3)^2
$$

Therefore the roots in $\displaystyle\,p\,$ are $\,p_{1,2}=\dfrac{3q+1\pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\dfrac{3q+1\pm (q-3)}{2}=\begin{cases}2q-1 \\q+2\end{cases}\,$, and the quadratic factors as $\,(p-p_1)(p-p_2)\,$.

Answer (score 1):

$$p^2-3pq+2q^2-p+3q-2=p^2-(3q+1)p+2q^2+3q-2=$$
$$=p^2-(3q+1)p+(2q-1)(q+2)=p^2-(2q-1+q+2)p+(2q-1)(q+2)=$$
$$=(p-(2q-1))(p-(q+2))=(p-2q+1)(p-q-2).$$

Answer (score 1):

Start as David Quinn suggested:
$$p^2-3pq+2q^2-p+3q-2=(p+Aq+B)(p+Cq+D).$$
Then plug $q=0$ and $p=0$:
$$p^2-p-2=(p+B)(p+D) \Rightarrow B=2; \ D=-1;$$
$$2q^2+3q-2=(Aq+2)(Cq-1) \Rightarrow A=1; C=2.$$